# streaming .m3u audio

Tags: android, audio, streaming

I want play streaming radio( .m3u format ), but i do not know how do it.

This example how i try playing:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mp.setDataSource("url.m3u");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

this code does not work.
help please.

Comment: may be this one help you :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283568/online-radio-streaming-app-for-android

http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/

Comment: check this link: https://github.com/abdullahfarwees/Android-Online-Radio-app

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to download the M3U file first. It's just a text file, read it line by line. Each line will have a link which you can read in your media player.

Use something like this,

```
public ArrayList<String> readURLs(String url) {             
        if(url == null) return null;
        ArrayList<String> allURls = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            URL urls = new URL(url);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urls
                    .openStream()));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                allURls.add(str);
            }
            in.close();
            return allURls ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: how can I use this with media player?

Comment: @user4292106 you can download the urls and then load it in the media player. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue with streaming radio. But in my case I've just removed **.m3u** from url and it worked!

Try to do this:

```
mp.setDataSource("url");
```

instead

```
mp.setDataSource("url.m3u");
```