# how to create android app for working with radio stream

Tags: android, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I want to add to my app an playing radio from url link.
I find something that I need but don't have the xml file is missing,here:

link: [Online radio streaming app for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283568/online-radio-streaming-app-for-android)

maybe some one have the xml file or anther example for doing that.
thanks a lot!

Comment: check this link: https://github.com/abdullahfarwees/Android-Online-Radio-app

Answer (score 1):

You can infere the xml from the code.

ProgressBar called progressBar1
Button called buttonPlay
Button called buttonStopPlay

Answer (score 1):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStopPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop" />
</LinearLayout>
```