# Audio Live stream: maximizing user base(decoding issue)

Tags: android

I'd like to build an application that will be based on live stream(radio). Here're some links I can start with: 1) [mp3](http://radio02-cn03.akadostream.ru:8114/detifm192.mp3), 2) aac("http://79.143.70.114:8000/detifm-64k.aac").

Unfortunately, those links couldn't be played by MediaPlayer on devices with Android 2.x. I'm a bit confused about this situation since [this piece of documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#network) states that HTTP/HTTPS live streaming draft protocol is only partially supported by the Android 2.x systems - for instance,my device(Samsung I9001) is not able to play links from above but able to play this one which is also an mp3 live stream as stated [here](http://www.live-radio.net/m.SearchResults.php3?OSt=Li&St=&OFee=Any&OCnt=Li&Cnt=&OPag=10&OSta=Li&Sta=&OCit=Li&Cit=county%20antrim&OGen=Li&Genre=). On other devices like Samsung GTS 5830 even the latest link can't played.

My goal is to maximize user base as much as possible - what can I do to achieve it ?

Firstly, I'm not really familiar with encoding/decoding technologies but, I guess, there're different ways to encode the same mp3, since [mp3](http://radio02-cn03.akadostream.ru:8114/detifm192.mp3) can't be played while "http://188.138.112.71:9018/"(City Beat Radio) can. So I need to know which types of encoding are more suited for Android and find out which one will be supported by the most of devices. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core) states "Mono/Stereo 8-320Kbps constant (CBR) or variable bit-rate (VBR)" - is this all I need to know ? What about playing  live streams on Samsung GTS 5830 ?

Secondly, decoding is dependent upon hardware. I've seen a library called [Vitamio](http://vov.io/vitamio/) that solves the issue of playing the first link, but I don't like the idea that user has to download additional third party software. Additionally, there's a [MoboPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clov4r.android.nil&hl=en) that also can play the first link. This is because they use *software decoding* - I wonder if there's any software decoding library I can incorporate into my project. I guess writing my own decoder would be tedious but your suggestions are welcome.

Thirdly, I've heard there's a way of live streaming through RTSP protocol, which is better supported by Android but I'm not familiar with this practice and haven't found any examples of mp3 live streams that I can check. Do you think it's worth trying ? And could you give an  example of live rstp mp3 stream ?

Here's simple code that I used to test. The first link([mp3](http://radio02-cn03.akadostream.ru:8114/detifm192.mp3)) resulted in `java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFF6` and the second([aac][2]) - `java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1`

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mMediaPlayer
            .setDataSource(
                this,
                Uri.parse("http://radio02-cn03.akadostream.ru:8114/detifm192.mp3"));
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mOnPreparedListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(mOnErrorListener);
        //mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

private OnPreparedListener mOnPreparedListener = new OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mplayer) {
        mplayer.start();
    }
};
```

**UPD**

LOGCAT for the first link(mp3) on Samsung I9001:

> 08-28 13:38:45.522: E/MediaPlayer(31713): message received msg=3,
>   ext1=0, ext2=0 08-28 13:38:45.542: E/MediaPlayer(31713): message
>   received msg=200, ext1=1, ext2=26 08-28 13:38:45.542:
>   W/MediaPlayer(31713): info/warning (1, 26) 08-28 13:38:45.552:
>   E/MediaPlayer(31713): message received msg=100, ext1=-10, ext2=-10
>   08-28 13:38:45.552: E/MediaPlayer(31713): error (-10, -10) 08-28
>   13:38:45.562: W/System.err(31713): java.io.IOException: Prepare
>   failed.: status=0xFFFFFFF6 08-28 13:38:45.562: W/System.err(31713):
>     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method) 08-28
>   13:38:45.562: W/System.err(31713):    at
>   com.example.sampleradioapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
>   08-28 13:38:45.562: W/System.err(31713):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   08-28 13:38:45.562: W/System.err(31713):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   08-28 13:38:45.562: W/System.err(31713):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   08-28 13:38:45.562: W/System.err(31713):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 08-28
>   13:38:45.562: W/System.err(31713):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   08-28 13:38:45.562: W/System.err(31713):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-28
>   13:38:45.562: W/System.err(31713):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 08-28 13:38:45.562:
>   W/System.err(31713):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 08-28
>   13:38:45.562: W/System.err(31713):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-28
>   13:38:45.562: W/System.err(31713):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 08-28 13:38:45.592:
>   W/System.err(31713):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   08-28 13:38:45.592: W/System.err(31713):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 08-28
>   13:38:45.592: W/System.err(31713):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-28 13:38:45.622:
>   I/MediaPlayer(31713): Info (1,26)

LOGCAT for the first link(mp3) on Samsung GTS 5830:

> 08-28 13:15:54.119: I/MediaPlayer(24178): uri
>   is:http://radio02-cn03.akadostream.ru:8114/detifm192.mp3 08-28
>   13:15:54.119: I/MediaPlayer(24178): path is null 08-28 13:15:54.119:
>   D/MediaPlayer(24178): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server
>   side 08-28 13:16:05.139: E/MediaPlayer(24178): error (1, -2147483648)
>   08-28 13:16:05.249: E/MediaPlayer(24178): Error (1,-2147483648)

LOGCAT for the second link(aac) on Samsung I9001:

> 08-28 13:40:46.681: E/MediaPlayer(31748): message received msg=100,
>   ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648 08-28 13:40:46.681: E/MediaPlayer(31748):
>   error (1, -2147483648) 08-28 13:40:46.681: W/System.err(31748):
>   java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1 08-28 13:40:46.681:
>   W/System.err(31748):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native
>   Method) 08-28 13:40:46.681: W/System.err(31748):  at
>   com.example.sampleradioapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
>   08-28 13:40:46.691: W/System.err(31748):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   08-28 13:40:46.691: W/System.err(31748):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   08-28 13:40:46.691: W/System.err(31748):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   08-28 13:40:46.691: W/System.err(31748):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 08-28
>   13:40:46.691: W/System.err(31748):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   08-28 13:40:46.691: W/System.err(31748):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-28
>   13:40:46.701: W/System.err(31748):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 08-28 13:40:46.701:
>   W/System.err(31748):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 08-28
>   13:40:46.701: W/System.err(31748):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-28
>   13:40:46.701: W/System.err(31748):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 08-28 13:40:46.701:
>   W/System.err(31748):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   08-28 13:40:46.701: W/System.err(31748):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 08-28
>   13:40:46.701: W/System.err(31748):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

LOGCAT for the second link(aac) on Samsung GTS 5830:

> 08-28 13:19:03.929: I/MediaPlayer(24352): path is null 08-28
>   13:19:03.929: D/MediaPlayer(24352): Couldn't open file on client side,
>   trying server side 08-28 13:19:29.119: E/MediaPlayer(24352): error (1,
>   -2147483648) 08-28 13:19:29.119: W/System.err(24352): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1 08-28 13:19:29.119:
>   W/System.err(24352):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native
>   Method) 08-28 13:19:29.119: W/System.err(24352):  at
>   com.example.sampleradioapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
>   08-28 13:19:29.119: W/System.err(24352):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   08-28 13:19:29.119: W/System.err(24352):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   08-28 13:19:29.119: W/System.err(24352):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   08-28 13:19:29.119: W/System.err(24352):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 08-28
>   13:19:29.119: W/System.err(24352):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   08-28 13:19:29.119: W/System.err(24352):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-28
>   13:19:29.119: W/System.err(24352):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 08-28 13:19:29.119:
>   W/System.err(24352):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 08-28
>   13:19:29.119: W/System.err(24352):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-28
>   13:19:29.119: W/System.err(24352):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 08-28 13:19:29.129:
>   W/System.err(24352):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   08-28 13:19:29.129: W/System.err(24352):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 08-28
>   13:19:29.129: W/System.err(24352):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: have you added INTERNET permission ?

Comment: could you please provide the full logcat output of the errors?

Comment: @herom, I've updated the thread - added logcats for both links on two devices: Samsung I9001, Samsung GTS 5830

Answer (score 1):

```
hi this may helps you
```

[streaminlike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283568/online-radio-streaming-app-for-android)

```
And Set MediaPlayer as
private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource("http://usa8-vn.mixstream.net:8138");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```