# MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648) when playing HTTP progressive MP3 stream

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, internet-radio

I've been trying so hard to develop an Internet radio Streaming app, but all I get it some force closes or errors.
Steps I've taken,

- I've read the MediaPlayer Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer#java).
- I've also read the already available solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269745/streaming-internet-radio-error-android).
- I've also searched google for any solutions but found none.

Here is my code:

MainActivity:

```
    private Button pbutton;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    pbutton = findViewById(R.id.button_play);
    pbutton.setEnabled(false);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://streams.abidingradio.org:7800/1");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pbutton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    pbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When I run this code, MediaPlayer is not getting prepared.
And it throws the following errors:
[click here for the full log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpT4b.png)
the main errors are:

```
failed to init data from source
MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

I've been dealing with this problem for almost three days but still haven't found a solution. I can also assure that the link of the audio stream is working perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is MediaPlayer doesn't support streaming MPEGA format. Take a look into [supported audio formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats).

Just use one of third-party players, which are compatible with, like [IjkPlayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer)
or [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I don't think the issue is with the audio stream. Because, I  used the same audio stream link in another sample app from GitHub and it worked fine. But when I use it here this happens. And BTW how would get to know the format of the audio stream.

Comment: "in another sample app from GitHub and it worked fine" - could i have a look on sample? "And BTW how would get to know the format of the audio stream" - Just open stream in any player and see 'video details' (vlc, mediplayer classic)

Comment: Here is the sample that I used [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaBrowserService/). To make it work, I just changed the dataSource to the stream link.

Comment: Thank you so much @Onix. I gave ExoPlayer a try and it works! Now there are new errors like "getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0" but it still streams the audio.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this.

**Declare:**

```
Uri alarmSound_carHorn;
Ringtone ringtone_carHorn;
```

**Initialize (onCreate):**

```
alarmSound_carHorn = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +  getApplication().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" +  R.raw.car_horn);
ringtone_carHorn = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),alarmSound_carHorn);
```

**When calling:**

```
if(ringtone_carHorn!= null && !ringtone_carHorn.isPlaying()){
    ringtone_carHorn.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but it was only on a few phones and I had no idea how to fix it. I ended up using [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer)

```
player?.apply {
        val mediaItem: MediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(url)
        setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        prepare()
        play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error only when onPause -> onResume was called.
It was caused by the setOnPreparedListener.
Solution:

```
binding?.playbackVideoView?.setOnPreparedListener(null)
```

clear on prepared listener so it doesn't use the old mediaPlayer object