# Audio stream in sdk 28

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm starting to build an application which will stream audio from url. Currently, as a starting point, using this approach [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40788661/7838447). And it works on my device (Android 7). However, when I sent it to few of my friends (one use android 7, two uses android 9), it didn't work on android 9 devices (stops at buffering stage). Any ideas why?

With Regards,
Eddie

Comment: The change log for Android 9 can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0#media). There are some changes to the AAudio API that would warrant further investigation.

Comment: @Malba thanks for your response. Will check it