# Using Android as Audio Input Output

Tags: android, audio, windows-7

I Have an Android and Windows 7 setup and my audio socket is not functional on my windows 7 machine, I want to use my android as a replacement for my audio socket enabling me to connect external audio devices such as headsets or speaker using Bluetooth or preferably  USB connection. Is this possible? I saw some article about using the phone as mic(input), but non so far for using it as input/output.

Answer (score 0):

Install for example JetAudio(with jetCast plugin) on windows 7 device, on jetCast create steam, on Android device you can used already existed radio player or crate your own [Online radio streaming app for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283568/online-radio-streaming-app-for-android).
Easy way.