# Trying to implement Media Player

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, internet-radio

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aD0WWoVDl0I
I have tried this code. Does nothing

My present code is this answer's
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6312631/10903899

Code

```
public class Radio2 extends Fragment {

private ProgressBar playSeekBar;
private Button buttonPlay;
private Button buttonStopPlay;
private MediaPlayer player;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_radio2, container, false);

    playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    playSeekBar.setMax(100);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    buttonPlay = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    buttonStopPlay = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    initializeMediaPlayer();


    return rootView;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonPlay) {
        startPlaying();
    } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
        stopPlaying();
    }
}

private void startPlaying() {
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    player.prepareAsync();

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.start();
        }
    });

}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        initializeMediaPlayer();
    }

    buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource("http://usa8-vn.mixstream.net:8138");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
    }
}
}
```

The worst part is that the stacktrace is empty, which means that im not getting any error in the catch blocks. The code inside the try block is executing. But nothing happens. I even tried changing the URL but nothing.

Comment: Could you try adding the following line to your catch statement? 

catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: There is still no exception @Mustafa

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger, just set breakpoints everywhere so you can follow what's happening